# vb.net Insert text into active textbox

Tags: vb.net

In a windows form, I have a button and two textboxes. When I click the button, I want some text to be added into the cursor position of the textbox that is holding the cursor.I know it's very simple to insert text into a textbox at cursor position. But with two textboxes,

I think about the focus property to determine which textbox is currently being typed in, but then as when I click the button, the focus jump to the button...

My question, how to know the "last focused control" .. or anyway to know if a textbox is being texted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inbuilt `LastFocusedTextBox` property.  It's simply up to you to remember.

```
Private lastFocusedTextBox As TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxes_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter
    lastFocusedTextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If lastFocusedTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
        lastFocusedTextBox.SelectedText = "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

You could use the `Leave` event just as well under the circumstances, but using `Enter` means that `lastFocusedTextBox` will contain the correct value in code while that `TextBox` has focus too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works good for me, especially when I don't have to go through all the textboxes in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Flag to check last TextBox focus:
Ex:

```
Dim iTxt=0
 Private Sub txt1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txtFile.MouseClick
iTxt=1
    End Sub
 Private Sub txt2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txtFile.MouseClick
iTxt=2
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I added a label that determines which text box is selected.

```
If textbox1 is selected then the label1.text = "textbox1"
// then the button will have this IF statement

If label1.text = "textbox1" then 
textbox1.text = "example"
end if 

If textboxt2 is selected then the label1.text = "textbox2"
// then the button will have this IF statement

If label1.text = "textbox2" then 
textbox2.text ="example"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I have invented a new way to know if the textbox1 or textbox2 has the focus, check it and enjoy.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim clr As Color = Nothing

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    clr = TextBox1.BackColor
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus
    Select Case sender.name
        Case "TextBox1"
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Navy
        Case "TextBox2"
            TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Navy
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus
    Select Case sender.name
        Case "TextBox1"
            TextBox1.BackColor = clr
        Case "TextBox2"
            TextBox2.BackColor = clr
    End Select
End Sub

End Class
```